# Wrong orientation when image captured by HTML5 file api on IOS 6.0

Tags: html, ios6, html5-filesystem

I am using HTML5 file api on mobile web app for image uploading utility.
I am capturing image using camera and upload it to server.
Problem is that if I capture portrait image the uploaded image automatically converted to Landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to transform the image to correct the orientation.  Fortunately, the image should include EXIF data that you can use to do that.  If you like, you can do this before the image is uploaded to your server:

1. Read the image's EXIF data
2. Use a canvas element to transform the image as appropriate
3. Export the canvas image into an image file

There's an excellent writeup, including code samples, in [this](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/take-and-manipulate-photo-with-web-page/) blog post.

Comment: updated invalid link from a link contributed by @btbJosh